# Got an error trying to join a domain

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-virtual-pc, domain

I have a Windows 7 machine, in which I've installed the Microsoft Virtual PC, so that I can have Windows XP on the Win7 machine. (I need it for some legacy development.) I've renamted the VPC and then rebooted. Next I tried to join the Active Directory domain (Windows 2003 R2 Server based), but I got an error that says:

"A domain controller for the domain MYDOMAIN could not be contacted.
The following error occurred when DNS was querieed for the sewrvice location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain MYDOMAIN:
The error was: 'DNS name does not exist'
(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)"

I know we have an DNS server, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Is the Windows XP VM on the same network as the host and the Domain Controller?

Comment: I would assume that the Windows XP VM is on the same network as the host. How could they be different?

Answer (score 2):

Can you ping your domain server from w/in the VPC? try pinging the fully qualified domain name, so if the server is test and your domain is example.com, you want to `ping test.example.com` and make sure you see an IP address in return, and that there is some activity there. If that works, try joining the domain using the fqdn instead.

**Update for comment**

It's possible then one or both of the following:

1)The server isn't responding to ping requests, but is up and running for you to join a machine. If that's the case, trying to join the domain using the fully qualified domain name should work.

2)The server is down or otherwise unconnected to the network. 'Down' in this case means not responding to domain requests, so it could be crashed, powered off, unplugged, etc. This is where you get the person who manages the domain server involved.

Comment: I cannot ping it, even when I fully qualify it. I do get the correct IP address, but the request times out.

Comment: I just tried joining the domain, and fully qualifying it (using your example, test.example.com), but I got the following error. "The network path was not found."

Comment: Yeah so likely that server is down for some reason similar to above, the client sounds fine, the only other thing is to make sure the domain controller and the client are on the same network.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm ignorant enough to think that since the host PC is on the network, the VM should also be on the network.

Comment: The easiest way is to compare the IP address of the VM with the IP address of the domain controller. on your VM, run `ipconfig /all` in a cmd prompt, and also note the subnet. In general, the first couple of octets should be the same for both IP addresses.

Comment: OK, I've just done as you suggested. The subnet numbers are identical, but the first couple of octels have nothing at all in common. From my Windows 7 PC the first it looks like this: 10.232. From the VM it's this: 192.168. So, how do I get the VM to get IP's from the same source?

Comment: @Rod what type of VM host are you using? there are usually network options such as 'bridged', etc., when configuring the the VM, you want bridged.

Comment: the VM host is Windows 7 Ultimate, 32-bit. I'll try to look at the network connections tomorrow when I'm at work.

Comment: I'm at work now, looking at the Network app in Windows 7. I don't see anything here about a bridge.

Comment: @Rod make sure you're using the host adapter that connects your host to the domain network, typically the LAN. This is set in the VPC settings, see here http://blogs.technet.com/b/windows_vpc/archive/2009/12/07/networking-in-windows-virtual-pc.aspx